# Python Pandas Lookup/Cross Referencing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge, ipython

I have two data frames:

```
In [6]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'word':['laugh','smile','frown','cry'],'score':[7,2,-3,-8]}, columns=['word','score'])
        df1

Out[6]:     word    score
        0   laugh   7
        1   smile   2
        2   frown   -3
        3   cry -8

In [8]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'word':['frown','laugh','play']})
        df2

Out[8]:
            word
        0   frown
        1   laugh
        2   play
```

I understand that I can merge them together and get a score for each word:

```
In [10]: pd.merge(df1,df2)

Out[10]:    word    score
         0  laugh   7
         1  frown   -3
```

However, I can't quite wrap my head around how to:

i) Automatically assign a score of zero to words that do not have a score. So, "play" is in df2 but is removed after the merge but I would like to keep it in the result after the merge. I expect df2 to contain many, many words that do not have a score so it is not possible to simply add these words to df1 and assign them as zero. So, I would want the merge to give this instead:

```
Out[10]:    word    score
         0  laugh   7
         1  frown   -3
         2  play    0
```

ii) How can I now get an average score for multiple words. So, if my data frame looked like this instead:

```
In [14]: df3 = pd.DataFrame({'words':['frown cry','laugh smile','play laugh', 'cry laugh play smile']})
         df3

Out[14]:    words
        0   frown cry
        1   laugh smile
        2   play laugh
        3   cry laugh play smile
```

I want to be able to cross reference df3 with df1 to get:

```
Out[14]:    words                 average_score
        0   frown cry              -5.5
        1   laugh smile            4.5
        2   play laugh             3.5
        3   cry laugh play smile   0.25
```

Hopefully I did the math right! I'm guessing that there might be another/better way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i) you just need to specify `right` join, and fill null values:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right').fillna(0)
    word  score
0  laugh      7
1  frown     -3
2   play      0
```

for (ii) you may do:

```
>>> def grpavg(ws):
...     i = df1['word'].isin(ws)
...     return df1.loc[i, 'score'].sum() / len(ws)
... 
>>> df3['avg-score'] = df3['words'].str.split().map(grpavg)
>>> df3
                  words  avg-score
0             frown cry      -5.50
1           laugh smile       4.50
2            play laugh       3.50
3  cry laugh play smile       0.25
```

edit: to answer the comment, pass the frame explicitly and then bind using either a `lambda` or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> def grpavg(ws, df):
...     i = df['word'].isin(ws)
...     return df.loc[i, 'score'].sum() / len(ws)
... 
>>> from functools import partial
>>> f = partial(grpavg, df=df1)
>>> df3['avg-score'] = df3['words'].str.split().map(f)
>>> df3
                  words  avg-score
0             frown cry      -5.50
1           laugh smile       4.50
2            play laugh       3.50
3  cry laugh play smile       0.25
```

Comment: if grpavg was placed inside a module then what would I need to do to ensure that df1 were accessible by this function (assuming that df1 is being read from a file)? Should I have a function that would read the list from a file and then change grpavg to take two arguments as input (ws and an optional data frame where this would be cross referenced)?

Comment: @slaw yes, the right way is to pass the frame explicitly. see edits